# Convert parallel to xargs command

Tags: xargs, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to convert this command to something that does not use parallel.

```
find . -type f -iregex '.*.ts\|.*.js\|.*.tsx\|.*.jsx' | parallel 'touch {} -d "$(date -d \@$((0x$(md5sum {} | cut -b 1-7))))"'
```

What I came up with does not work

```
find . -type f -iregex '.*.ts\|.*.js\|.*.tsx\|.*.jsx' -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | cut -b 1-7 | xargs -0 -I {} touch -d \@0x{}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to set the files mtime to its md5sum for caching purposes

Comment: (1) Please explain what you are trying to do. (Put your explanation ***in*** your question; we don’t like links.)  (2) What you’re trying doesn’t look very much like what you’re starting with. (3) For the purpose of asking a clear question, can you simplify your ```find``` command?

Comment: Which `parallel` are you using? GNU `parallel`, [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parallel) or another?

Comment: GNU parallell...

Comment: I made a simple script 



`file=$1`

`md5=$(date -d \@$((0x$(md5sum $file | cut -b 1-7))))`

`touch $file -d $md5`



and changed my command to 


`find . -type f -iregex '.*.ts\|.*.js\|.*.tsx\|.*.jsx' -print0 | xargs -0 -L1 ./build/set-mtime-to-md5.sh`

but it is now making files that are equal to $md5

Answer (score 1):

You do not write the reason why you want to convert the script. Maybe you want the script not to depend on GNU Parallel.

If that is the case you might be interested in `parallel --embed` which will embed GNU Parallel in a shell script:

```
parallel --embed > newscript
```

Then edit the end of `newscript`.

You can then use `newscript` on machines that do not have GNU Parallel installed.

`--embed` has been available since version 20180322.

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` is not so radically different from GNU `parallel`
that you need to radically change the structure of the command. 
This

```
find . <find_args> -print0 | xargs -0 -L 1 sh -c 'touch "$1" -d "$(date -d @$(( 0x$(md5sum "$1" | cut -b 1-7) )) )"' sh
```

works.

Moreover, on my system, you don’t need to use `date -d`; `touch` can also
handle `-d @number`, so you can do

```
find . <find_args> -print0 | xargs -0 -L 1 sh -c 'touch "$1" -d "@$(( 0x$(md5sum "$1" | cut -b 1-7) ))"' sh
```